# SQLite query to compare dates

Tags: date, sqlite

I have two text columns (**valid_from** and **valid_to**) in a table (**history**) in SQLite database in which I am storing date in **dd/MM/yyyy** format.

Now I am running following query to fetch all the records between **June 1, 2018 to June 30, 2018**, but I am not getting any results:

**Try 1:**

```
SELECT * FROM history WHERE valid_from >= datetime('01/06/2018') AND valid_to <= datetime('30/06/2018');
```

**Try 2:**

```
SELECT * FROM history WHERE cast(strftime('%Y%m%d', valid_from) as integer) >= cast(strftime('%Y%m%d', '01/06/2018') as integer) AND cast(strftime('%Y%m%d', valid_to) as integer) <= cast(strftime('%Y%m%d', '30/06/2018') as integer);
```

Nothing fetched the records. Am I missing something?

Comment: _Don't_ store your dates in `dd/MM/yyyy` format in SQLite.  Always use ISO format `yyyy/MM/dd` instead.  There are workarounds, but they are ugly, and it would be better to fix your data.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - Its already stored like this. I cannot do much about this. I have to find the solution with this format only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should *always* store your date information in SQLite in an ISO format, where the year comes before the month, which comes before the day.  The reason for this is that in SQLite dates are just stored as plain text, and your current format won't sort properly.  As a workaround, you may try the following query:

```
SELECT *
FROM history
WHERE
    SUBSTR(valid_from, 7, 4) || '/' || SUBSTR(valid_from, 4, 2) ||
        '/' || SUBSTR(valid_from, 1, 2)
        BETWEEN '2018/06/01' AND '2018/06/30';
```

Here we are just building the correct date format for each date.  But again, the best long term solution is to fix your date data.